# Should [potted-plants] be a synonym of [container-gardening]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I asked a question today involving potted plants. With it I made the tag [potted-plants](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potted-plants). I was kind of confused how that tag hadn't been created before, but I later remembered that we had the tag for [container-gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/container-gardening).

Should the tag [potted-plants](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potted-plants) be a synonym for [container-gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/container-gardening)?

Answer (score 3):

Why not let the community decide?

[I've suggested](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/container-gardening/synonyms) the tag [potted-plants](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potted-plants) as a synonym of the tag [container-gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/container-gardening), so users with 5 or more reputation in the [container-gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/container-gardening) tag [(see all six users who currently qualify)](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/container-gardening/topusers) can [vote on whether or not it is a good synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work).

-2 votes will delete the suggestion, +4 votes will approve it. I [replaced it](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/posts/13995/revisions) back onto [your question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13995/do-i-have-to-bring-my-potted-plants-inside-during-the-winter), so that it has a question, and doesn't self destruct.

If the suggestion is deleted, we can remove the tag from your post, and with no questions, it should be gone in the next day.

Comment: voted, who knew this was even possible? I think I would call voting on tag synonyms to be hidden feature of SE